# how to LOOKUP on a TABLE per SET of ID and END_DTTM_FLG

Tags: sql, oracle, lookup

I hope you could help me!

The requirement is to **clean-up/delete the INACTIVE records from TABLE_2**.

**INACTIVE record criteria** is when `ID` records have `END_DTTM IS NOT NULL` and there’s NO partner record of the same `ID` with `END_DTTM IS NULL`.

Meaning if an `ID` has `NULL END_DTTM`, that `ID` is still ACTIVE.

I made a query first to get the INACTIVE records then I'll just add the DELETE syntax when I got the correct data.

**SAMPLE QUERY:**

```
WITH SRC1 AS (
SELECT ID 
  FROM TABLE_1
 WHERE END_DTTM IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT ID 
  FROM TABLE_2 
 WHERE TABLE_2.ID = SRC1.ID
;
```

Please check attached sample data.

[image]

Issue is that, the query still gets the ACTIVE records (`ID` with `END_DTTM IS NULL`) because there's the same `ID` with `END_DTTM IS NOT NULL`.

I have also tried to create a `END_DTTM_FLG` --> `case when END_DTTM IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END END_DTTM_FLG`. My idea is to lookup the `ID` per set, if `ID` has `END_DTTM_FLG =2` then the `ID` corresponding to that should not be fetched.

**How can I lookup the `TABLE_1` and check the `ID` per SET of `END_DTTM_FLG`?**

Please help me solve this problem!

Thank you! ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I understood it.

For sample data (altering session just to set date format; you don't have to do that):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from table_1 order by id, end_dttm nulls last;

        ID END_DTTM
---------- ----------
4157061694 21.06.2021
4157061694 21.06.2021
4157061694 23.06.2021
4157061694
4157064676 19.01.2021
4157064676 20.01.2021

6 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table_2;

        ID
----------
4157061694
4157064676
```

Delete rows from table_2 whose IDs are "inactive" in table_1:

```
SQL> delete from table_2 b
  2  where not exists (select null
  3                    from table_1 a
  4                    where a.id = b.id
  5                      and a.end_dttm is null
  6                   );

1 row deleted.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table_2;

        ID
----------
4157061694

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> delete from table_2 b
  2  where b.id not in (select distinct a.id
  3                     from table_1 a
  4                     where a.end_dttm is null
  5                    );

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * from table_2;

        ID
----------
4157061694

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Littlefoot! I got the SQL query using NOT IN. Thank you for this! ^__^
May I asked what cost more? NOT IN or NOT EXISTS? 
The table_1 has 5million records and table_2 has 800K+ records. 
My query is running too long... :( 
What can you suggest to be able to lessen the runtime? 
Again, thank you! ^__^

Comment: You're welcome. It is difficult to say; run them both and compare. Are ID columns indexed? What does explain plan say for both of those options? Maybe you could create a separate table of active IDs, then truncate the original table and move those "separate" rows back (beware, TRUNCATE is irreversible, you can't rollback it!).